# Updating Data From Multiple tables in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Let us say I have three tables T1, T2 and T3 in redshift.I want to create a separate table by joining these tables.How can I update the data in the 4th table if there is any change in either T1, T2 and T3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try using a `view` instead for the 4th table. So something like this:

```
create view T4 as (
    select
        ....
    from T1 ...
    join T2 ...
    join T3 ...
)
```

Views are like 'stored queries', so everything you query T4 it will use the latest data in all the other tables